# How Can I Make Dynamic Search Form While Converting Html To Wordpress?

Tags: search

I Am Converting Html to Wordpress. I Can Make Simple Searchform through

```
<?php get_search_form( $echo ); ?>
```

But I want to show Nothing Found if it can't find any data through search.
How Can i Do that , any help?

Answer (score 1):

In your `index.php`, you should have something a bit like:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- HTML -->

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

        <!-- Post content -->

    <?php endwhile ?>

    <!-- HTML -->

<?php endif ?>
```

You can extend this code to say "if no posts and is search, display message":

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <!-- HTML -->

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

        <!-- Post content -->

    <?php endwhile ?>

    <!-- HTML -->

<?php elseif ( is_search() ) : ?>

    <!-- No posts and is search, show message -->

<?php endif ?>
```